# TS Function Type with Multiple Signature

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I write this in the vscode and there is no error and warning. But I wonder if this type can be instantiated, if so, please give me an example, thanks!

```
type MyFunction = {
    (x:any):boolean;
    (x:any, y:any):boolean;
    desc:string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is this:

```
const myFunction: MyFunction = (x: any, y?: any) => true

myFunction.desc = "Brian’s custom function";
```

Comment: I got this point, thanks!

Comment: If I add the third specification like this type MyFunction = {
    (x:any):boolean;
    (x:any, y:any):boolean;
    (x:any):string // new one
    desc:string;
}, is it still possible to write one?

Comment: Followup questions generally don't belong in comments; you might consider opening a new question for it.  Note that `{(x: any): boolean; ⋯ (x: any): string;}` doesn't make too much sense, since the first call signature would always be selected in practice.